# BTRFS: List the Crc's of a file's blocks

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, file-metadata

How can I output the Crc's of a file's blocks?

I made a copy of a file using reflink, and I want verify if the original and copied contents are still the same. My intent is to compare the Crc's on both files.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to compare them by CRC, but it appears possible to compare them by their extents using `filefrag -e`

```
sudo filefrag -e ORIGINAL COPY
Filesystem type is: 9123683e
File size of ORIGINAL is 2545747541 (621521 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..  143487: 1337824475..1337967962: 143488:             shared
   1:   143488..  390015: 1337466112..1337712639: 246528: 1337967963: shared
   2:   390016..  621520: 1337203968..1337435472: 231505: 1337712640: last,shared,eof
ORIGINAL: 3 extents found
File size of COPY is 2545747541 (621521 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        0..  143487: 1337824475..1337967962: 143488:             shared
   1:   143488..  390015: 1337466112..1337712639: 246528: 1337967963: shared
   2:   390016..  621520: 1337203968..1337435472: 231505: 1337712640: last,shared,eof
COPY: 3 extents found
```